# default language based on user profile language selected

Tags: reactjs, react-native, internationalization, react-redux, react-i18next

I am working on the language translation using i18n. I have a ToggleSwitch to change the language of the content which is working fine. But I want to make the default language according to user profile language selected.

This is the code I am using.

Any help?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this._retrieveData()
    this.state = {
        isOnBlueToggleSwitch: false
    }
}
onToggle = (isOn) => {
    I18n.locale = isOn ? "th" : "en"
}
_retrieveData = async () => {
    try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
        if (value !== null) {
            localLanguage = JSON.parse(value);
            I18n.locale = localLanguage.lang;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ToggleSwitch
                onColor="#52a557"
                size='small'
                isOn={this.state.isOnBlueToggleSwitch}
                onToggle={isOnBlueToggleSwitch => {
                    this.setState({ isOnBlueToggleSwitch });
                    this.onToggle(isOnBlueToggleSwitch);
                }}
            />
        </View>
    )
}
```

### i18n.js

```
'use strict';
import I18n from 'react-native-i18n';

I18n.fallbacks = true;

// List of language
I18n.translations = {
    'en': require('./en'), //for English
    'th': require('./th'), 
};

export default I18n;
```

Comment: can you add your i18n.js file also

Comment: @Kranthi I have updated my question

Comment: Did you try whether the locale is getting updated in _retrieveData method if you manually change to en' or 'th' ? just to see whether the locale is updating or is problem somewhere

Comment: @Kranthi if I add         I18n.locale = "th"; before try then it is working but i awnt to get the data from AsyncStorage

Comment: Check whether the code is going to onToggle method(by using alert or console) and if it goes try assigning locale directly to 'en'or 'th'

Comment: nope i have tried removing onToggle function too once I put this code after AsyncStorage.getItem .. it not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179801/discussion-between-kranthi-and-s-s).